# Getting an error when loading component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting an error when trying to load my component:

> Failed to load
>   bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false)
>   with error:(Unable to resolve module `components/Items` from
>   `/Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/Home.js`: Module
>   `components/Items` does not exist in the Haste module map
>
> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf
>   /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`. (null))

Trying to load my component in screen which is called screens/home.js, which is then loaded in my app.js.

Added this to the top of the /screens/home.js file:

```
import Items from 'components/Items';
```

And calling it in the render like this `<Items />`

components/items.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const Items = () => {
  return (
    <View>This is now an item</View>
  )
}
export default Items;
```

Why can't I load a component? Tried doing what the error says.

[image]

Comment: Is items a custom component? if so then it's probably './component/Items'

Comment: Show the folder/file structure of your project, please.

Comment: Added @ChrisCousins

Comment: Try: import Items from '../components/Items'

Comment: You probably meant to write `import Items from '../components/Items'`. You have to go one directory up from `screens` to `app` before the relative path `components/Items` points to the correct file.

Comment: @rottenoats When switching to import Items from './components/Items';



Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `./components/Items` from `/Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/Home.js`: The module `./components/Items` could not be found from `/Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/Home.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist

Comment: @FK82 Thanks, switched to that. But now I get a new error. Like the above, plus: 

Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `/Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/components/Items(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
  * `/Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/components/Items/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)` (null))

Comment: @vemund Sorry my bad, you want lowercase "i": `import Items from '../components/items';` That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `import Items from '../components/items'`, actually your file is named `items` (without capital i) instead of `Items`.

Answer (score 1):

If the file location is right as you mentioned, `import Items from '../components/items';` should be right.
But the important thing is after you add new files such as js or image files, you need to restart the node modules.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

import Items from '../components/Items';

Comment: Not working. Then I get: 
Failed to load bundle(localhost:8081/…) with error:(Unable to resolve module ./components/Items from /Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/Home.js: The module ./components/Items could not be found from /Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/Home.js. Indeed, none of these files exist